# Understanding Abel Ruffini theorem

Tags: quintics

Due to efforts of Abel, Ruffini, we know that there does not exist a general formula for a quintic equation. But given a specific quintic, say $x^5+5x^2-97x+1001=0$, Can there exist a root for it in radicals not necessarily involving the coefficients?

Comment: Your example has Galois group $S_5$ (according to Maple), so its roots can't be expressed by radicals.

Comment: Radicals involving rational numbers, that is.

Comment: But there **are** quintics that have roots expressed in radicals.  For example, quintics that are not irreducible over the rationals.